# Query to get the "Item -- (1,n) --> Attributes" relation table?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

given is the following database scheme and I am wondering how to build the appropriate query on a Postgres system.

It is defined that Items can have multiple (1 -> n) Attributes which relation is specified within the Relation table.
This relation table also stores a value related to this connection.
Also  items and attributes can be added or removed any time, but the relation table will always only contain valid item and attribute ids.

```
Item
----
id (primary key), name

Attribute
---------
id (primary key), name

Item_Attribute_Relation
-----------------------
Item.id, Attribute.id, value
```

Now my task is to return a (sparse) table where items are shown as rows and where each attribute is given as a column.
As an example following table shows the Attributes (A, B, C, and D) and the Items (a, b, c, and d).
The entries relate to the value in the Item_Attribute_Relation.
It is possible that an attribute (column) is NULL for every item and that an item has no attributes at all.

```
   | A | B | C | D |
--------------------
 a | x | x | y |   |
 b | x | z |   |   |
 c | w |   |   |   |
 d |   |   |   |   |
```

Unfortunately my SQL knowledge is rusty and Postgres does not support PIVOT to my knowledge.
Also I am not able (probably due to missing knowledge) to dynamically generate the columns when using the Postgres crosstab() function.
My gut tells me that this is a common problem. Therefore help by providing the correct wording or by posting links to this problem explanations is also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What about returning the attribute/values in a single JSONB column instead? That would make things a lot easier

Comment: Oh, have not been aware of Postgres Json capabilites, yet :) Indeed, a **row_to_json(item_attribute_relation)** where I can merge all Json objects which have the same **item_id** would fulfill my current use case.